# I've create trigger to change Buddhist Thai Year to Christian Year but insert more than 1 error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've create trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YearBuddhistToChristian]
    ON [dbo].[Syslogd]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       if (select year(MsgDateTime) from inserted) = year(getdate()) + 543

    INSERT INTO Syslogd(MsgDateTime,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText)
    SELECT dateadd(year,-543,MsgDateTime),MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText
    FROM inserted;
    else
    INSERT INTO Syslogd(MsgDateTime,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText)
    SELECT MsgDateTime,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText
    FROM inserted;


    END
```

but when I insert more than one it's error 
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure YearBuddhistToChristian, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

How can i fix this

Comment: you need to put your 'YEAR' logic into a single INSERT statement with a CASE statement in the SELECT

Comment: I concur. Your select in the IF returns all rows from the current insert (which is a table that can hold more than one row). After the INSERT INTO ... SELECT a CASE should hold that logic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within your IF condition. You're comparing a set to a single value:

```
if (select year(MsgDateTime) from inserted) = year(getdate()) + 543
```

This works fine if you insert a single record because the select will evaluate to a single value, but on an insert with multiple records you're essentialy comparing a list of multiple values to a single value, and SQL server recognises that two objects of different types (a set, and a scalar value) are not comparable.

You could rewrite the trigger to move the 'IF' statement into the select, in the form of a CASE statement, where it will be evaluated for each row:

```
    INSERT  INTO Syslogd
            (MsgDateTime,
             MsgPriority,
             MsgHostname,
             MsgText
            )
            SELECT  CASE WHEN YEAR(Inserted.MsgDateTime) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                              + 543 THEN DATEADD(YEAR, -543, MsgDateTime)
                         ELSE MsgDateTime
                    END,
                    MsgPriority,
                    MsgHostname,
                    MsgText
            FROM    inserted;
```

Alternatively, you could use this wherever the insert is occurring to avoid the need for a trigger (for instance in a stored procedure).

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your 'YEAR' logic into a single INSERT statement with a CASE statement in the SELECT 
something like

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YearBuddhistToChristian] ON [dbo].[Syslogd] INSTEAD OF INSERT AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; 

--if (select year(MsgDateTime) from inserted) = year(getdate()) + 543

INSERT INTO Syslogd(MsgDateTime,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText)
SELECT CASE WHEN year(MsgDateTime) = year(getdate()) + 543  THEN dateadd(year,-543,MsgDateTime) ELSE MsgDateTime END AS MsgDateTime
,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText
FROM inserted;
--else
--INSERT INTO Syslogd(MsgDateTime,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText)
--SELECT MsgDateTime,MsgPriority,MsgHostname,MsgText
--FROM inserted;


--END
```